# Fuse 6.2, fabric and camel-bindy: unable to resolve dependecy

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, fabric8, bindy

I have a camel-route that uses camel-bindy to transform data.
I'm using features to defined all the needed bundled for the route to work and in my pom I have the dependecy for camel-bindy.

I create a container in Fabric and add a custom profile whose parent is "feature-camel". I added the camel-bindy feature and my own feature to this profile (NB I obtain the same result if I do not add camel-bindy esplicity).

The container try to start the camel route but failed and this is the error:

> Unable to start blueprint container for bundle customBundle due to unresolved dependencies [(&(dataformat=bindy)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormatResolver))]

This is what I found in the log a couple of minutes before the error:

> DeploymentAgent updated with {attribute.parents=mytria-demouno, fabric.zookeeper.pid=io.fabric8.agent, feature.camel-bindy=camel-bindy, feature.camel-blueprint=camel-blueprint, feature.camel-core=camel-core, feature.esercizio1-feature/2.0.0=esercizio1-feature/2.0.0, feature.fabric-agent=fabric-agent, feature.fabric-camel=fabric-camel, feature.fabric-core=fabric-core, feature.fabric-git=fabric-git, feature.fabric-git-server=fabric-git-server, feature.fabric-jaas=fabric-jaas, feature.fabric-rest=fabric-rest...

If I look at the bundle pages of the hawtio console for the container I can see that camel-bindy has been deployed and has the expected version.

This is the features file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="esercizio1-feature_repository">
    <feature name="esercizio1-feature" version="2.0.0">
        <feature>camel-blueprint</feature>
        <feature dependency="true">camel-bindy</feature>
        <feature>camel-sql</feature>
        <feature>spring-jdbc</feature>
        <feature>camel-cxf</feature>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:it.demo/mysql-fragment/2.0.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.32</bundle>  
        <bundle>mvn:it.demo/esercizio1/2.0.0</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

I also try to change the parent for the profile and put fuse-full, but nothing changes... any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!** Just post the solution if someone need it.

There was a stupid error in the felix maven bundle plugin.

Must be:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <version>2.5.3</version>
```

I had 2.3.7, probably was the good one for Fuse 6.1.